# knockout update observable on ajax success function without reloading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using knockout in my MVC 4Application for view model binding. I need to update my view model fields on Ajax success function without reloading the whole view model. I am using the following code to update the view model fields. But issue is that on the update of each view model filed value, whole viewmodel is reloaded which ends up in circular request of calling  updateHiddenElements method.

Here is my View Model

```
function ViewModel(data) {

      var self = this;
      self.Fields = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
        return new FormField(item);
      }));
      self.HiddenElements = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(self, false);
      self.applyUpdates = ko.computed(function () {

      if (self.dirtyFlag.isDirty()) {
          //alert("YES !!!");
           updateHiddenElements(self);
           setTimeout(function() {
           self.dirtyFlag.reset();
           }, 0);
       }
     });
};
```

Here is my update method,

```
var updateHiddenElements = function (viewModel) {
 //alert("Posting Data:\n\n"+ko.toJSON(viewModel));
 //console.log("#### SENDING AJAX REQUEST TO FETCH LIST OF ELEMENTS TO BLANKOUT ####\n");
   $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("GetBlankoutElements", "Offer")' +  "?OfferID=" + @Model.ID,
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
             success: function(result) {
               result.split(',').forEach(function(name) {
               var param = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.Fields(),  function(currentParam)
               {
                    return currentParam.Name() == name;
               });
               if (param) {
                            param.Value(param.Default());
                           }
              });
              viewModel.HiddenElements(result.split(','));
             }
          });
 };
```

Can anybody suggests me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the whole viewmodel can be completely reloaded. But I don't understand why the updateHiddenElements function is not implemented directly inside the viewmodel. This would seem to me much more logical and I think it might clear your problems. The 'success' functions does than work directly on the viewmodel and you don't have to pass the whole viewmodel around.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    ...
    updateHiddenElements = function () {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("GetBlankoutElements", "Offer")' +  "?OfferID=" + @Model.ID,
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: ko.toJSON(self),
           success: function(result) {
             result.split(',').forEach(function(name) {
             var param = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Fields(),  function(currentParam)
                           self.HiddenElements(result.split(','));
             }
             ...
           });
       });
}
```